# Using ffmpeg for creating H.265 video compatible with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, video-encoding, video-codecs

Windows 10 supposedly supports H.265, but I can't get it to play files encoded with H.265, which appears to be the current best format.

I'm running it like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -r 60 -i "video_%04d.png" -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main10 -level 3.0 out.mp4
```

I don't want to install codecs or extra software, I just want it to open on any Windows 10 platform without extra software.

Comment: I don't think it likes 10bpp, try main profile instead of main10.

Comment: Does Windows 10 support H.265 at all? It's very hard to find that information online, since they mostly list the supported container formats only.

Comment: According to this its supported:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt218785(v=vs.85).aspx
Not sure how to set the main profile in ffmpeg, it complains about "main" instead of "main10". Still Microsoft page says Main10 is supported. So I'm not sure whats wrong...